# vscode: how to change color of recently used file background base on git status

Tags: visual-studio-code

same with title [how to change color of recently used file background base on git status.]
idea:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMs1z.png)
vscode:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMJjh.png)
there is no background color shown.
I search on vscode doc but nothing found.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you want git decorations in the Quick Open picker. If it's not already a thing, which it looks like it isn't, you'll need to [raise a feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md). Also, if quick open is built on [the quick-pick API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#QuickPickItem), this would probably require deeper changes to the model and API... good luck!